# Using github actions to post tweets

Tags: python, github-actions

I am posting tweets using twitter's(X) api. Below is the code which will get triggered from github actions.

```
name: Post Tweets to Twitter

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Adjust this to your repository's default branch

jobs:
  tweet:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8  # Adjust this if needed

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install tweepy

      - name: Read and Post Tweets
        env:
          DISPLAY: ":0"  # Set the DISPLAY environment variable
        run: |
          #!/usr/bin/env python3
          import tweepy

          consumer_key = ""
          consumer_secret = ""
          access_token = ""
          access_token_secret = ""

          auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
          auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

          api = tweepy.API(auth)

          with open("tweets/tweets.txt", "r") as file:
              tweets = file.read().split("\n\n")

          tweeted_tweets = []
          try:
              with open("tweeted_tweets.txt", "r") as tweeted_file:
                  tweeted_tweets = tweeted_file.read().split("\n")
          except FileNotFoundError:
              pass

          new_tweets = [tweet_text for tweet_text in tweets if tweet_text.strip() and tweet_text not in tweeted_tweets]

          if new_tweets:
              for tweet_text in new_tweets:
                  try:
                      # Add the -X option to disable X server
                      tweet = api.update_status(status=tweet_text, x__options=['-X'])
                      tweeted_tweets.append(tweet_text)
                      print("Tweeted:", tweet_text)
                  except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                      print("Error:", e)

              with open("tweeted_tweets.txt", "w") as tweeted_file:
                  tweeted_file.write("\n".join(tweeted_tweets))

      - name: Commit and Push Changes
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "justinmamathew@gmail.com"
          git config --local user.name "mathewjustin"
          git commit -am "Update tweeted tweets"
          git push
```

The code does the following.

reads tweets from tweets.txt, tweeted_tweets.txt file is used to keep track of already tweeted tweets. Before posting new tweets, the workflow reads this file to identify tweets that have already been posted. Only new tweets are posted, and their content is added to the tweeted_tweets.txt file to prevent duplicate tweeting.

But when the trigger excecutes it returns me this error.

```
Run #!/usr/bin/env python3
import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/346.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running this in shell not in python. This is why you got this error. You can try this

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
      - uses: jannekem/run-python-script-action@v1
        with:
          script: |
            import os
            print("Directory contents:")
            for f in os.listdir():
                print(f)
```

or save it as python script and execute it. You can check it [here](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/run-python-github-actions/)

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?